# Bind every model field with a certain object

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have an Article model, where I write some article. Also, in my site, I have a slider with 3 images. I created a model.

```
class SliderImages(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = 'slider'
    image_1 = models.ImageField()
    image_2 = models.ImageField()
    image_3 = models.ImageField()
```

How to bind every image with some Article? In django admin, I want to upload image and bind it to some article, and then in slider every image will have a link to a certain article

Update post:
[image: current situation]

Desired situation(one Article for one image)
[image]

[image: I don't need that Article Block below]
Code for this:
Models:

```
class Slider(models.Model):
    article = models.ManyToManyField(Article)

class SliderImages(models.Model):
    slider = models.ForeignKey(Slider, null = True, related_name= '+')
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, null = True, related_name= '+')
    image = models.ImageField()

    class Meta():
        db_table = 'slider'
```

and in admin.py:

```
class SliderInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = SliderImages
    max_num = 3

class SliderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [SliderInline,]

admin.site.register(Slider, SliderAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add three foreign keys to articles:

```
class SliderImages(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'slider'
    article = models.ManyToManyField(Article)
    image_1 = models.ImageField()
    image_2 = models.ImageField()
    image_3 = models.ImageField()
    article_1 = models.ForeignKey(Article, related_name='+')
    article_2 = models.ForeignKey(Article, related_name='+')
    article_3 = models.ForeignKey(Article, related_name='+')
```

And then use fieldsets in `admin.py` to place image_N/article_N in one row:

```
class SliderImagesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('article', ('image_1', 'article_1'),
                                  ('image_2', 'article_2'),
                                  ('image_3', 'article_3'),)
        }),
    )    
admin.site.register(SliderImages, SliderImagesAdmin)
```

[image: SliderImages form screenshot]

Comment: @Andrew what is wrong with this fieldsets?  See screenshot, it looks exactly like your mockup.

Comment: Извините, моя ошибка. Могу ли я реализовать модель и админку так, чтобы у меня сначала был один блок (изображение - статья), и я мог добавлять нужное мне количество таких блоков?

Comment: Yes, you can. If you want a growing list of images then use recipe from @PhoebeB.

Comment: But I already have ArticleAdmin for adding and editting articles

Comment: You don't need to overwrite your whole `ArticleAdmin` class. Just add `inlines = [SliderInline]` line to it.

Comment: Perhaps, you misunderstand me. Article admin and SliderImages admin must be separated from each other. Because, I will have just one object of SliderImages, and multiple objects of Articles. If I do as PhoebeB writes, I will have to choose three images for one article. It's not that I need

Comment: Then create two models. `Slider` with `m2m` to `Article` and `SliderImage` with `fk` to `Slider`. `SliderImage` should contain two more fields: `ImageField` and `fk` to `Article`.  In `admin.py` create modeladmin for `Slider` with `SliderImage` inline. See @PhoebeB's code for example.

Comment: Watch my last image in the post. What do I need Article block below? I don't need it. And the list is not growing. I just need the same as you replied me in your post, but in that case I have 3 image fields and 3 article fields in model. I'm asking whether I can do it, but with 1 image field and 1 article field, and the admin will decide number of images and articles( len(images) = len(articles))

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `ForeignKey` with the model object that you want to bind to, and set the normal Django binding to that Article Object:

```
class SliderImages(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = 'slider'
    article = models.ManyToManyField(Article)
    image_1 = models.ImageField()
    image_2 = models.ImageField()
    image_3 = models.ImageField()
```

Comment: I will have 1 article for 3 images then. I need 3 articles for 3 images

Comment: I edited my answer.  You can use a `ManyToManyField` to accept multiple ForeignKeys for Model Objects.

Comment: see image in updated post. I need to choose for every image one article. It need to be something like in one row: choose image and choose article

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign a number of images to each article, then:

```
class SliderImages(models.Model):

  article = models.ForeignKey(Article)
  image = models.ImageField()

  class Meta():
    db_table = 'slider'
```

Then in admin, you make SliderImages an inline to article, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.StackedInline

```
class SliderInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = SliderImages
    max_num = 3

class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
       SliderInline,
    ]
```